# Get distinct data based on min time MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a sample data here:

[image]

And here is my desired output:

[image]

How can i get the distinct value based on min time?

here is the update i tried

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery for filtering is probably the easiest solution:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp = (select min(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.id = t.id
                    );
```

You may need to take the date into account if you want the earliest record overall:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.date, t.time) in (select t2.date, t2.time
                           from t t2
                           where t2.id = t.id
                           order by t2.date desc, t2.time desc
                          );
```

or if you want the earliest record on each date:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp = (select min(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.id = t.id and
                           t2.date = t.date
                    );
```

Comment: sorry sir but did not get the output i need :(

Comment: and took so long to before the data shows

Comment: i fix the query but it gave multiple rows

Comment: @myownemail . . . I am guessing that you also care about the date.

Comment: sorry for the inc. info yes sir including that

Comment: i get the result but it is not the same as the result i need, multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL 8.0, window functions are usually the most efficient way to proceed:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col4) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

With earlier versions, I would use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mytable t1 WHERE t1.col2 = t.col2 AND t1.col4 < t.col4 
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g6MPFw8MQA4zfgo8bZoW8P/3)**:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3       | col4     | col5       |
| ---- | ---- | ---------- | -------- | ---------- |
| 2    | AAA  | Customer 1 | 07:00:00 | 2019-03-04 |
| 3    | BBB  | Customer 2 | 15:00:00 | 2019-03-04 |
```

For this to perform efficiently, you would need an index on `mytable(col2, col4)`:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_idx ON mytable(col2, col4);
```

---

If you have more than one record with the same `col1` and `col2`, you can add an additional criteria to avoid duplicates in the resultset, using column `c1`, which I understand is the primary key of the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM mytable t1 
    WHERE 
        t1.col2 = t.col2 
       AND (
           t1.col4 < t.col4 
           OR (t1.col4 = t.col4 AND t1.col1 < t.col1)
       )
)
```

**[Updated DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g6MPFw8MQA4zfgo8bZoW8P/4)**.

Comment: sorry sir but did not get the output i need :(

Comment: @myownemail: please have a look at the [link to the db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g6MPFw8MQA4zfgo8bZoW8P/2) that I provided in my answer. Given your sample data, these queries do produce the expected output. What is wrong, from your perspective?

Comment: our column 1 is different mine is unique, i try the second one and it took so long while the 1st one has an error but i think because of my low MYSQL version

Comment: @myownemail: column 1 does not make a difference in this case (I still updated my answer and the fiddle).

Comment: noted on that i will try again

Comment: So basically the second query is taking too long? This does not mean that it does not work... I added a recommendation in my answer to create an index.

Comment: tried the second one but the ouput is not the same as what i expected multiple columns instead of the unique based on min time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189365/discussion-between-gmb-and-myown-email).